# Fedora hanging on boot with just underscore displayed

Tags: fedora, boot, linux-kernel

When trying to boot into Fedora 24, it is hanging when I select kernel version 4.7.3 or 4.7.4 from the grub menu, but if I select 4.7.2, it boots normally. When it hangs, just an underscore is displayed on the screen, and it doesn't respond to any keyboard input (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). I edited the boot command line to remove "quiet" and "rhgb", and it prints a lot then stops at 1.6 seconds - the lines displayed on the screen mostly talk about USB and inputs to begin with, then  `Freeing unused kernel memory` and `write protecting the kernel read-only data`, then the last thing logged is two lines of `random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 24 bits of entropy available)`, though the last copy of it is cut off - the line is too long to be displayed as one, and the first is split over two lines but the second has the last bit cut off.

I think this might be related to me unsuccessfully trying to install the nvidia proprietary drivers following [this guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/). I thought I had rolled everything back though. The one that works, 4.7.2, is the version where I was trying to install the nvidia drivers - I had backed up the initramfs file, and restored it when rolling back. The versions created after that are broken.

Adding the `nomodule` parameter to the grub command line allows it to get further than before, but it still doesn't work properly - it gets to `Sterted GNOME Display Manager` and `Started Virtualization daemon`, then the screen just starts flashing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> works, but keystrokes aren't reliably registered.

Comment: Trying booting with the kernel arguments `nomodeset` or `single`. What results do you get? If you can at least get into your system debugging will be a lot easier, so getting a terminal is the first goal.

Comment: @Centimane Neither of those parameters work, but `nomodule` did work (though was a bit glitchy), and I am able to boot using an older copy of initramfs that was created before I tried to get the nvidia drivers to install (but it's stuck on the 4.7.2 kernel because versions built for more recent versions break).

Comment: I wouldn't expect the NVIDIA driver to have an effect on you initramfs, the nvidia module should be loaded during `init` of `fedora` itself. `single` should put you into single user mode, which strips out a lot of services (which makes it much more likely to successfully boot). I would pursue getting single user mode to work.

Comment: @Centimane do you have any suggestions for where to start? I am definitely able to boot with `nomodule`, but `single` doesn't work, and hangs at the same place as everything else.

Comment: Include both, `nomodule single`.

Comment: You can also try adding `module_blacklist=nvidia` instead of `nomodule`. Since you'll need kernel modules for other things, if you suspect the nvidia module is the problem, better to prevent only it from being loaded.

Comment: @Centimane `module_blacklist=nvidia` didn't work, but `nomodule single` does. Is there any way to list the modules that will be loaded by an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to solve this now - it turns out that, as well as `/etc/modprobe.d`, there is also `/usr/lib/modprobe.d`, and while I had removed the nvidia installer's nouveau blacklist file from `/etc/modprobe.d/`, I hadn't removed the one in `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/`, so nouveau wasn't being loaded. Deleting that file means that it's working now.

I discovered the extra config file by running

```
diff <(sudo lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-4.7.4-200.fc24.x86_64.img) <(sudo lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-4.7.2-201.fc24.x86_64.img) | less
```

and looking through the differences until I found something suspicious. There is a lot of noise (all the kernel drivers have changed path), but fortunately this was fairly easy to spot.